# how to publish ios unity wrapper into unity asset store?

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I have written, an ios framework (compatible with unity, as a unity wrapper).
*.framework file.

is it possible to publish it in unity asset store? if yes, how?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a Unity Asset to me. It's an iOS framework so I don't think it will be approved on the asset store.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing to the Asset Store
This is the basic workflow for publishing your assets to the Asset Store:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetStorePublishing.html